# Getting turbolinks wrapper to work with Ruby on Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, turbolinks

For my App, I am trying to set up the Turbolinks Mobile wrapper> . I am running into an issue where I can't sign into the App (and thinking the issues is that I need to modify Devise to get it to switch to XHR to work for the mobile).  My sign_in form uses Devise but I can't see the code.

`Using:
ruby "2.4.0"
gem "rails", "5.0.2"
gem "turbolinks", "~> 5.0.0.beta"
gem "devise", ">= 4.2.0"
gem "devise-async", git: "https://github.com/mhfs/devise-async", branch: "devise-4.x" # for user authentication`

My question is where to I look or what do I need to do to amend DEVISE to have it be able to send the XHR for the turbolinks mobile wrapper?

Right now, it won't sign in and I know (or I am thinking) I need to get DEVISE to switch to XHR but I don't know how.

Suggestions on how to do this?  Or recommendations on reference material?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update your devise initializer to accept ajax requests.

```
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html, :json]
```

You will probably need to update your registration and session controllers to respond to json also.

```
format.json { render json: resource }
```

Comment: Hi Stephen,
Thanks - Bounty is all yours!  Quick question, i added the format.json right here (just on create) - does that make sense: http://take.ms/pihdd

Many thanks for the answer.

Comment: The eager loading isn't specific to the JSON response. That warning is just telling you that you are loading data that isn't used. Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations