# Devise redirect to on successful login seems to get stuck on first login attempt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm developing a small application using Ruby on Rails and using Devise for authentication. I've two login systems setup and one is `user` and the other one is `employee`

When logging in using correct email and password, devise sends the correct redirect to path back but it gets stuck there. Nothing continues unless I refresh the page. But once I refresh it, it will happily go to the redirect path and even if after logging out in the same browser tab and then logging back in works. But if I close the tab and then load the application in a new tab, it doesn't work.

Following is the rails server output when logging in,

```
Started POST "/employees/sign_in" for ::1 at 2020-06-21 18:21:50 +0530
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Pr0k+3+FfU72BcwTVRhWxQYBTD/zcv5+QBdWuovDRd4+yGxC1OBWmvAscWJbnog2vVTLpbPM2xOwVxGC3UsLRg==", "employee"=>{"email"=>"employee@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
  Employee Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "employees"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "employee@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:23
  CACHE Employee Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "employees".* FROM "employees" WHERE "employees"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "employees"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["email", "employee@example.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:23
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/employee/dashboard
Completed 302 Found in 818ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

I'm not sure why this happens and hitting a dead end when trying to find anything related to this error.

Following is the code for my after_sign_in_path function

```rb
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    set_flash_message! :alert, :warn_pwned if resource.respond_to?(:pwned?) && resource.pwned?
    set_root
    # super
  end
```

Here `set_root` function returns a String with the path for the redirect.

Version information

```
Ruby version - ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x86_64-darwin19]
Rails version - Rails 5.2.4.2
Devise version - 4.7.1
Turbolinks - Yes
```

Comment: Have you tried `redirect_to set_root` ? Returning a string doesn't have any sense.

Comment: @cmramseyer yes. But that resolves to a `DoubleRenderError - “Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action”` so it doesn't work.

Comment: @cmramseyer it's supposed to return a string, and that string is redirected to by the method that called `after_sign_in_path_for`

Comment: This scenario seems pretty difficult to debug with the information you've provided. Have you overwritten devise's session controller in any other way? If so, could you add it? Also, where's your app hosted? What happens if you change rails_env to production? I'd advise rewriting the sessions controller entirely based on the devise source code and putting a debugging mechanism there.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn yes. You're correct. It does suppose to return a string and that string will be used for the redirect. Still, I tried the method `redirect_to` but as I've said, it didn't work.


@cesartalves Thank you for your comment.   

1. I haven't overwritten devise session controller in any way. I haven't generated any custom controllers for devise. Only views and the model.    
2. This does appear on both Localhost and Heroku. On Heroku, I'm using the production build. 

Thank you. Will try the rewriting thing and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing your `form_for` with `form_with` in your `sessions/new.html.erb`. I have a similar problem (Rails 6) and it seems to be ok now.

```
<%= form_with(model: resource, scope: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Additionally, I uncommented the `Turbolinks` section in `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:devise_failure_app) do
  include Turbolinks::Controller
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Weirdly this seems to fix the issue. I have already enabled active support TL controller but that wasn't resolving the issue. But changing `form_for` to `form_with` seems to resolve it. However, I'm not sure why this actually works. Any idea on why?

Comment: I think it's something to do with the `remote` behaviour and Turbolinks. With `form_for`: `<form class="new_user" id="new_user" action="/users/sign_in" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">`, with `form_with`: `<form action="/users/sign_in" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">`. I'm not sure anyway, but I'm glad this solves our problem :)

Comment: I faced the same problem. It does work with this answer, but here we changed to use the remote form, which means we need to response javascript code when the sign in is failed, for example.

@MarceloSotoMontes, do you have other solutions?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an issue with your frontend (more specifically Turbolinks) rather than the backend. As your log shows, the redirect actually happens from an HTTP standpoint.

Since I haven't run into this issue myself (mainly because I haven't used Turbolinks much in more complex apps), I can only point you to a few resources that describe issues similar to yours, namely:

- [Getting turbolinks wrapper to work with Ruby on Rails Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42860934/getting-turbolinks-wrapper-to-work-with-ruby-on-rails-devise)
- https://www.oarod.com/2017/01/29/turbolinks-with-devise/

I hope one of these two helps.

If not, feel free to share some frontend code – like I said, I think the issue is on the frontend, not the backend.

Comment: Thank you. I already implemented the first SO fix but to no avail. Since I don't have custom controllers for devise, I cannot implement the controller fix. My login is fairly normal, will share a link.

Comment: Please find the login page code in this pastebin
https://pastebin.com/60JTsfyt

Comment: Is there any particular JavaScript code that might influence this bit of code that you've posted?

Comment: I don't think so. Apart from few small JS bits, nothing major is there.

Comment: Then I would do the usual debugging dance and remove as much code as possible and get the feature into a working state and then gradually add back code until it starts breaking again. In your case, I'd start with not loading any JS (= comment out/remove all `javascript_include_tag` statements) and try if it works. If it does, enable JS again, remove all `require` statements from `application.js` and other manifest files and add them back one by one. My assumption is that this way you'll find the offending piece of code.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would try is to do a return redirect_to :

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  set_flash_message! :alert, :warn_pwned if resource.respond_to?(:pwned?) && resource.pwned?
  return redirect_to set_root
  # super
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried this already and confirmed that this doesn't work. And removing pawned message also didn't yield any success.